# Seeking photo editing advice but picture is 7MB - where to upload it?

Tags: discussion, support

One photo from my camera has a really strange effect that I don't understand - either what caused it or how to fix it.

I can't upload it here because of the 2MB limit, but imgur seems to compress it even worse. I'd like to show the full image "as I see it" since that might give clues what has gone wrong, and because the effect can't be seen other than in full resolution (and compression might add more artifacts). The pic is about 6.8 MB.

Where's a good place to upload large images, or what should I do if seeking input on a large picture?

(On an aside, may be worth adding a good answer on this, to the site FAQ as I'm probably not the only one who will have a photo editing question on a >2MB pic)

Comment: Does your question *need* the full picture? Or is it enough to add a downsampled image and a separate actual size portion cropped out to show the problematic part? (This also avoids having to add directions such as "look in the bottom left half, just north to that yellow dot above the green splash, and zoom in to see a weird looking pixel".)

Comment: In this case it needs the full pic, as that might reveal for example if its localised (camera lens/chip issue?), effect due to a visible lighting source elsewhere, limited in some way, or some other cause. Its a weird effect across much of the pic, but does seem to have some variance? But its also a very obvious issue on a moment's look;  it won't need "pointing out".

Comment: Based on the short description of the issue, it seems this is more about photography than graphic design. Just want to let you know that there's a sister site which solely focuses on that: [photo.se]. You might want to check that site too.

Answer (score 2):

I would upload a screenshot of the image (as a thumbnail) and then also upload the image to a (free) online file sharer.

I personally like to use https://nofile.io but you can even use Dropbox or GoogleDrive.

It is important to make sure that

a. your question is very specific (regardless of the file)

b. the file is very clearly an image (don't upload a zip file) folks will likely not download that.